# "Message Contains No Documents" when attempting to insert into Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am building a Ruby on Rails app that utilizes the Mongoid gem to store data through Mongodb.

My issue comes from this rake task:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

task :scrape => :environment do

  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&source=embed&dg=feature&authuser=0&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208523333872813891131.0004c02beb4f2788337d0'))

  page.css("coordinates").each do |coords|    
    coords = coords.text.split("\n")
    coords.each do |coord|
      array = coord.strip.split(',')
      array[0] = array[0].to_f
      array[1] = array[1].to_f
      if (array[0] != 0 && array[1] !=0)
        puts array[0]
        puts array[1]
        s = Submission.new(array[0], array[1], "Calfire", nil)
        s.insert
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `s.insert` attempts to put the information taken from the URL, create an instance of a `Submission` and then insert it into the Mongodb database.  Each time I run `rake scrape` in terminal, I get the following error as it tries to save the `Submission` in the database.

```
-122.952888
40.741924
rake aborted!
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=83
  @request_id=3
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="fireapp_development.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 13066: "Message contains no documents"
```

I am fairly new to both Ruby and Mongodb so if any other code would be helpful, it can update this post with it.  I tried setting up a new app/scaffolding to see if that would fix it but nothing changed.  I also tried just saving an instance of `Submission` through terminal but that didn't work either.

When googling for a solution I came across this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/kg-wK56_JkQ

It suggests that I might not be querying anything, but the `puts` lines in the Ruby code clearly outputted into the terminal.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:

The fields for the `Submission` model

```
class Submission
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :lat, type: Float
    field :long, type: Float
    field :image, type: Moped::BSON::Binary
    field :category, type: String
end
```

EDIT 2:

The issues were fixed by properly formatting the `s.create` line as well as removing the `s.insert` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard usage is [`Model.create(attributes)`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html), you should be doing just:

```
s = Submission.create(:lat => array[0], :long => array[1], :category => 'Calfire')
# No Submission.new, no s.insert, just create and check s.valid? or use create!
```

I suspect that `Submission.new` doesn't really know what to do with all those positional arguments so you're probably some sort of confused nonsense in `s`. Presumable `Submission.new` is trying to interpret the arguments and silently failing.

Comment: I will edit the original post to add the `Submission` model and thank you for your response, I will attempt it.

Comment: If you look at the EDIT on my original post you can see the `Submission` model. I have attempted doing `s = Submission.create(:lat => array[0], :long => array[1], :category => 'Calfire', :image => nil)` but I got the error saying I have one too few arguments. Any ideas?

Comment: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3..4)`

Comment: You're sure that's from `Submission.create`? And there's nothing else suspicious inside `Submission`?

Comment: Have you perhaps added a `def initialize(lat, long = nil, category = nil, image = nil)` to your `Submission` perhaps?

Comment: You're right there was `def initialize` in `Submission` that I just cleaned up.  Unfortunately I'm looking at a new error now. `Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command`

Is followed by `failed with error 11000: "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: fireapp_development.submissions.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('53feb543434a731463000000') }"`

Comment: You should never see a duplicate `_id` ObjectId unless something is really screwed up. Does it complain on every `create`? Is it always the same ObjectId? Anything else strange in `Submission`?

Comment: The original post is updated to have the entire submission.rb code and I just tried running `rake scrape` in terminal and I got a different ObjectId and it exits after it complains the first time.

Comment: Are you still doing `s.insert`? Anything familiar [in here](https://www.google.ca/#q=mongoid+mongodb+duplicate+key+error+index)?

Comment: I am still doing `s.insert` and I haven't found anything yet, but I'm going to keep poking around that Google search.